# Django migrations, added field before deleting old

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

**14:**

```
operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
            name='add_on',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
            name='add_on',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, to='account.SubscriptionAddOn'),
        ),
    ]
```

**15.**

```
operations = [-------------------------SCROLL DOWN TO SEE FIELD--------------
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
        name='add_on_display_order',
        field=models.BooleanField(default=0),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
        name='add_on_is_deleted',
        field=models.BooleanField(default=0),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
        name='add_on_last_updated',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
        name='add_ony_created_date',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
        name='monthly_created_date',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
        name='monthly_display_order',
        field=models.BooleanField(default=0),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
        name='monthly_last_updated',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(---------------------ADDED-------------------
        model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
        name='add_on',
        field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='account.SubscriptionAddOn'),
    ),
    migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(----------OF ANOTHER TABLE-------------
        name='storecredits',
        unique_together={('store', 'credit_type')},
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
        name='created_date',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
        name='last_updated',
    ),
    migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(---------THIS BOUGHT ME HEADACHE----------
        name='storesubscriptionplan',
        unique_together={('store', 'add_on')},
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(---------------------REMOVED-------------------

        model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
        name='add_on',
    ),
]
```

In the 14th migrations i choose to make my add_on field from foreign key to many-to-many so woked fine, then i choose to make it back to foreign key. As you can see in 15th migration it created the field before removing it and then removed the field, his made field deleted in the database table, when I visited django admin it gave me error no add_on_id exist, so I looked at table structure, it wasn't there as it was deleted, and since then everything went wrong, though in next migration when i changed a field name, it created the field as:
**16**

```
operations = [
    migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
            name='add_ony_created_date',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
            name='add_on',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='account.SubscriptionAddOn'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='storesubscriptionplan',
            name='add_on_created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Is there something i did wrong?
As fields were unique together, it later gave me error no constrain to drop, duplicate fields, and then things went out of control.

Comment: did you un-apply all the migrations and re-run them again?

Comment: no i don't know how to do that, i tried deleting add on, store and unique_together and then make migrations, this made things even worse as it had unique constrain but the field was deleted by django

Comment: Okay, run `python manage.py appname zero`. `Zero` flag unapplies all your migration after that run your the migrations again.

Comment: all means, re-create every table? though am creating tables, if i had it in production with data, would it be right to un-apply all migrations?

Comment: thanks @ans2human i'll re apply them, hope that work, can you brief me please, will it delete and re-create all table for app?

Comment: It doesn't affect your data while in production. It just brings you back to `initial0001` migration.

Comment: No, it will not affect your data. **Just to un-apply all your migrations** -  
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#migrate

Comment: i resolved the problem, can you please explain me if it was my error only or django has some kind of constrains that it does so? so as i don't make this mistake again

Comment: Using `zero` right?

Comment: no i used fake migrations

Comment: to make structure as in database and then changed accordingly

Comment: still am confused why django created the field before deleting unlike in 14th migration, and then added unique together constrain and then deleted it, the constrain remained and bought me errors

Comment: this might help you. - https://www.algotech.solutions/blog/python/django-migrations-and-how-to-manage-conflicts/